# HTTP Status 404 error

Tags: java, jsp

HI,
I have deployed a war named test in the JBoss AS. When i go to browser and type the url http://localhost:8080/test, i get the login.jsp page, which is the welcome page. when i hit the submit button a servlet gets invoked name CheckLoginServlet (onSubmit i have redirected to /test/servlet/CheckLoginServlet), on successful login this servlet redirects to a jsp (MFrame.jsp) which is inside the docroot/main/jsp, and the url looks like this http://localhost:8080/main/jsp/MFrame.jsp?sid=13045798560,and i get a 404 error, the reason is that the url is not including the context "test", now when i explicitly modify the url in the browser to include test in it,(now the url looks like htttp://localhost:8080/test/main/jsp/MFrame.jsp?sid=13045798560)  the page successfully renders. My question is why the context test is not coming in the url, as it is the context root.

Answer (score 2):

> my question is why context is not included in the url.

Well the obvious answer is that what ever produced that URL has a bug in it.  Beyond that, we'd only be guessing ...

If you'd care to show us the code fragment (or JSP fragment or whatever) in context that created the URL, maybe we could offer a better answer.

Comment: sLocation = "/admin/jsp/Display.jsp?sid=" + sessionID;

Comment: this is the url, login page is going to i have not included the context root in this url as it should implicitly take it. the context root is test. so do i need to do like this                      sLocation = "/test/admin/jsp/Display.jsp?sid=" + sessionID

Comment: you are providing the absolute URL. remove the leading / and then the url should be relative to your context

Comment: did as per you suggestion , but still getting the same problem.

Comment: @java_dev - in response to your first comment, basically yes.  The link URL that you output has to either be the full absolute URL including the context path, or a relative URL that will resolve relative to the URL of the base URL of the page containing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly [setting the context root](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIOverrideTheWebContextRoot) to "test".